# Why is this giving me a divide by zero error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why is this giving me a divide by zero error? I would like this to return the count of the records in the database with stated parameters. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbcrms.ccars.ci_submission_history
    where crms_dt = '2016-12-31' 
        and totalliabilities <> null or totalliabilities <> 0
            and mra_required = 'Yes'
                and committedexposure / totalliabilities <= 1
```

I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Because you forgot the parentheses

Comment: totalliabilities worth zero

Comment: Because at least one row has a value of 0 for totalliabilities and there are no parenthesis.

Comment: I didn't think this is valid NULL comparison - `totalliabilities <> null`.  for Null comparison like this, you must use `totalliabilities IS NOT NULL`, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot guarantee the order in which your clauses will be evaluated, so `committedexposure / totalliabilities` may be evaluated before `totalliabilities <> 0`

A workaround setting `0` to `null` with `nullif()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbcrms.ccars.ci_submission_history
    where crms_dt = '2016-12-31' 
        and totalliabilities <> 0
            and mra_required = 'Yes'
                and committedexposure / nullif(totalliabilities,0) <= 1
```

And `<> null` should probably be `is not null`, which will be true if `totalliabilities <> 0`, so it is redundant.

Also, be aware that [`and` takes precedence over `or`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms190276.aspx) as far as logical operators go. It would be best to wrap your each side of your `or` so that it is clear what you want to accomplish.